# Proper way of collecting data from multiple sources for a single item

Tags: python, web-scraping, request, scrapy, meta

This is a thing I've been encountering very often lately. I am supposed scrape data from multiple requests for a single item.

I've been using request meta to accumulate data between requests like this;

```
def parse_data(self, response):
    data = 'something'

    yield scrapy.Request(
        url='url for another page for scraping images',
        method='GET',
        meta={'data': data}    
    )

def parse_images(self, response):
    images = ['some images']
    data = response.meta['data']

    yield scrapy.Request(
        url='url for another page for scraping more data',
        method='GET',
        meta={'images': images, 'data': data}    
    )

def parse_more(self, response):
    more_data = 'more data'
    images = response.meta['images']
    data = response.meta['data']

    yield item
```

In the last parse method, I scrape the final needed data and yield the item. However, this approach looks awkward to me. Is there any better way to scrape webpages like those or am I doing this correctly?

Comment: I do it the same way. The only alternative I can think of for this would be to yield different types of items and then combine the output in an item-pipeline. This would require storing possibly a lot of data in memory so I would consider your current approach to be the better one still.

Comment: @WimHermans Yes, that was the thing I was asking for, like yielding item partially between parse methods and combining at the end, but this is better I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the proper way of tracking your item throughout requests. What I would do differently though is actually just set the item values like so:

```
item['foo'] = bar
item['bar'] = foo
yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse, meta={'item':item})
```

With this approach you only have to send one thing the item itself through each time. There will be some instances where this isnt desirable.

Comment: Does this make a significant time improvement over sending the response content?

Comment: It just keeps you from having to name and send multiple variables through.

Answer (score 2):

it's quite regular and correct approach keeping in mind that scrapy is async framework.
If you wish to have more plain code structure you can you use [scrapy-inline-requests](https://scrapy-inline-requests.readthedocs.io/en/stable/readme.html)

But it will require more hassle than using `meta` from my perspective.